Насколько сложно будет распознавать цифры с накладной? Если это вообще возможно?
Собираюсь писать в качестве диплома программу по подсчету накладной по ее фотографии.
На фото уже посчитанные накладные в качестве примера (непосчитанные без заполненного столбца "сумма", они все выглядят идентично, иногда бывают выходы за сетку. Никогда не работал с компьютерным зрением и OCR. С питоном работал в рамках разработки тг-бота, есть опыт back-end разработки на php, чуть анализа данных в рамках одной из дисциплин, заканчиваю факультет Информационных технологий. Хотелось бы узнать насколько сложна будет реализация распознавания именно цифр с накладной (На то что смогу распознавать названия товаров я не надеюсь), т.к. главное это подсчет всей суммы товаров. Пользовался сервисами по распознаванию, никто не распознал текст, но с числами треть справилась (и то с некоторыми ошибками). Знаю что есть инструменты вроде easyOCR, tesseract, google Vision, но думаю даже с ними будет трудно. Расскажите пожалуйста с какими трудностями я столкнусь именно в моем случае и вообще насколько это возможно, т.к. некоторые препода говорят что у меня ничего не выйдет, уже и сам расстроился. Так же буду благодарен, если подскажите ресурсы для обучения в данной области и может даже направите меня в поиске решения моей задачи.



задача по распознования рукописных цифр решена. Если хотите поиграться, то это чисто совет, можете использовать GAN, посмотреть интерактивно как это работает можете здесь https://poloclub.github.io/ganlab/. Если CNN, то это AlexNet, VGG. Данных тоже достаточно, если мне память не изменяет то в свободном доступе большой датасет MNIST.

вопрос ваш размыт и вряд ли на него будет дан ответ. Переформулируйте так, чтобы можно было конкретный ответ. "С какими трудностями" вы столкнетесь никто вам не подскажет. Задачи и методы их решения выбирать вам. Курс по машинному обучению, любой университетский будет наилучшим решением (мнение)

для CNN тоже интерактивчик нашел https://poloclub.github.io/cnn-explainer/

Программа на диплом не тянет. Для диплома вам нужно будет постараться дать ответ на вопрос "Почему распознавание рукописных чисел работает не очень хорошо?" и предложить пути улучшения. В общем, будет сложно.
